# Sqlite for Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I m developing an app similar to uber with android as front-end with rest api to serve data which is stored in mysql.

I would like to know if sqlite is used instead of mysql to achieve the above process because of the reasons sqlite exist in phone and data 'll be deleted after uninstalling the app.

Comment: You can use whatever database you want to but first go and study.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sqlite database in android is used to store data which will not be stored in the backend but inside your phone only which you would not like to fetch from network everytime! for instance- user's ride history or user specific data. Although they'll need to be updated in regular interval.

In mysql you would need to store the backend data. so these two are two different things.

i hope you understand the diff among these and if you don't you should read a lot about these.